# Laravel 5.7: Why do my model create() and save() methods create 2 records when called?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model

I am using mysql DB, Laravel 5.7, on Apache.

I already have a full system running, and all seems to be fine, except...I decided to start using some eloquent factories for testing, and noticed that the factories were making 2 entries in mysql when I save/create a model.  So I simplified, and created my own "makeFake" method, and find that its doing the same thing.  I don't know what I have done wrong.  Or maybe there is some area of the framework that I do not fully understand.

Main question: Why do my model create() and save() methods create 2 records when called?

Simplified case below...  (in this case, I am calling 2 methods to create a company, but I am getting 4 company records)

From my web.php

```
Route::get('/savingTest', function () {

    $company = App\Company::makeFake1();
    dump($company);

    $company = App\Company::makeFake2();
    dump($company);

    return 'complete';
});
```

From my Company.php model (I already loaded faker and GUID libraries)

```
public static function makeFake1()
{
    $faker = Faker::create();
    $company = new Company;
    $company->code = $faker->word;
    $company->name = $faker->company;
    $company->guid = Guid::create();
    $company->save();
    return $company;
}

public static function makeFake2()
{
    $faker = Faker::create();
    return Company::create([
        'code' => $faker->word,
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'guid' => Guid::create(),
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Please copy your code to your question, don't use images.

Comment: Did you refresh the route? Clean your DB table and test again.

Comment: The code editor, just has JS and HTML and CSS sections, not PHP.   Do I just put in into the JS box?

Comment: No, put on the body of the question, select the code and use CTRL + K . You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited to replace images with code.

Comment: vivek_23 ... Yes I did clear the routes cache and the db and tried again.   The first request to the URL produced 6 records,  and any request after that produced 4 records.   Really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

I found the issue....so frustrating.

I've been struggling to see where my code was broken, but I find that Chrome Browser is sending double requests.  When I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/test1 in the URL bar, Chrome sends TWO get requests against the Web server, not one.

IE is working fine, and firefox is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

### There is a difference between save() (new) and create()

[Laravel Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

[Laravel Inserts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts)

When you call create() it instantly creates a new eloquent model item and commits it to the database.

When you call the new method, it creates the eloquent model item but DOES NOT commit it to the database.

If you are wanting to amend the items in the item depending on other factors, then use new followed by save() at the end. If you want to mass create items with plain data, then use the create() function.

Therefore, the following code created 2 items:

```
$faker = Faker::create(); // First Record created
$company = new Company;
$company->code = $faker->word;
$company->name = $faker->company;
$company->guid = Guid::create();
$company->save(); // Second Record created
```

Comment: This section "$faker = Faker::create(); // First Record created" is operating on a different object.  The faker object, not the company.  Why would it create a company record?

Comment: Hmm fair point, have you considered installing Debugbar to help diagnose the issue and see what queries run?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  It turns out that my Laravel install may be corrupted.  See my answer to this question.

Comment: You don't have anything duplicated in your database config file do you?

Comment: Petay87 - You may be on to something.  I did make a change to the /config/database.php file recently.  I just added a sqlite_testing section.  However, I am using mysql, so I did not think anything of it.  Maybe there is a typo in the file now causing some kind of confusion in eloquent.  I am going to try a vanilla database.php file and see if that makes any difference.